# Reading variables from App settings in .Net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

In my solution I have a project "Project A" where I have following code reading "DataStore" section from appsetting.json file in following way:

```
 public class AzureCosmosDBSettings
    {
        public string Instance { get; set; }
        public string Database { get; set; }
        public string Collection { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
    }

    public class RecordingStoreSettings
    {
        public AzureCosmosDBSettings AzureCosmosDB { get; set; }
        public AzureBlobSettings AzureBlob { get; set; }
    }
 static public class ServiceLocator
    {
        static ServiceCollection _serviceCollection;

        static public IServiceProvider Provider { get; private set; }

        static ServiceLocator()
        {
            _serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureServices( _serviceCollection );
            Provider = _serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        private static string GetBasePath()
        {

            return Path.GetDirectoryName( System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location );
        }

        private static void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath( Path.Combine( GetBasePath() ) )
            .AddJsonFile( "appsettings.json", optional: false )
           
            var config = builder.Build();   
            
            services.AddSingleton<MyClass>();
            services.AddTransient<OutputTableStore>();
            services.AddOptions();
            var recStoreSettings = new RecordingStoreSettings();
            config.GetSection( "DataStore" ).Bind( recStoreSettings );
// these are key value pairs in recording store
            if( recStoreSettings.AzureCosmosDB != null )
            {
                services.AddTransient<ITwisterDocumentStore>( ( sp ) => new CosmosDBDocumentStore(
                    key: documentStoreSecret ?? recStoreSettings.AzureCosmosDB.Key,
                    instance: recStoreSettings.AzureCosmosDB.Instance,
                    database: recStoreSettings.AzureCosmosDB.Database,
                    collection: recStoreSettings.AzureCosmosDB.Collection ) );
            }
```

And now I have to read this key-value pairs of DocStore in a different class in a different project ProjectB in same solution. After the reference, I defined the dependency injection in one class like one below in project B:

```
public class MyParentClass
    {
 private MyClass _myClass = null;

        protected MyClass MyClass
        {
            get
            {
                if( _myClass == null )
                    _myClass = ServiceLocator.Provider.GetService( typeof( MyClass ) ) as MyClass;

                return _myClass;
            }
        }
```

Now, I have created a class which is inheriting from the "MyParentClass" but I am struggling in reading the appsettings value of docStore. Need guidance how can I continue this code reading the value of app settings in this project. Thanks

Comment: You can add the options for `RecordingStoreSettings` object and later inject at required classes.

Comment: where should I add the options? can you be more specific?

Comment: You can define like this `Services.AddSingleton<RecordingStoreSettings>(recStoreSettings);`. now the same can be injected in class B constructor like `public MyParentClass(RecordingStoreSettings recordingStoreSettings)`

Comment: can you please provide it as an answer? may be more specific above in my code above where to add